# Which individual airframe has carried the most passengers in its lifetime?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, statistics

I'm guessing that the airframe will be one of the 747s that service the domestic Japanese market, making regular short hops full of passengers - but perhaps actual figures exist to confirm this.

See also: [Which airliners have carried the most passengers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57887/which-airliners-have-carried-the-most-passengers) for a related question about passengers carried by an aircraft series.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between this and the other question? Certainly an aircraft that carries the most passengers is an airliner, no?

Comment: Do you mean one aircraft, or one make and model of aircraft?

Comment: As the title says, and in distinction to the other question, this is about *individual aircraft*.

Comment: An answer would be possible if there are public databases linking airframe number and total passengers carried. It's unlikely such database exists, think of an airframe being used by successive operators for example: The owner of this database must be above the operators and registration countries, meaning IATA or manufacturer. But such information has little visible interest for them (in addition the number of boarding passengers is not significant, it can be x2 just by the presence of a stopover in the middle of the trip -- else the passengers*km value should be looked after)

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably have to be a Boeing 737 or A320.

Comment: Talking total body count over the lifetime of the aircraft, rather than max for a single flight, right?  If it's not one of the early model 747s, I'll bet it's a DC-3/C-47/Dakota... 70-80 years of short flights *might* outcount half that time with longer flights even at higher loading.

Comment: Probably the closest you could get is if a database exists that has the number of flights for each airframe. Then you could use an average load factor based on whatever airline statistics might be available, such as average load factor per type, per airline, etc. But there would probably be many airframes that are in the same general range, for example airframes that were built around the same time that flew with only one airline for their entire careers. With the statistical uncertainty you might at best maybe narrow it down to a particular type that flew with a particular airline.